# como establecer un radio en google maps api e identificar si estoy dentro del rango?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api

Buen dia, estoy utilizando la api de google de mapas para obtener las coordenadas de una ubicacion mediante el search o dando click en este caso sobre el mapa y guardando esa ubicacion en base de datos esta ubicacion representa el lugar donde esta ubicado mi centro de trabajo, ahora quisiera establecer un radio en metros a la redonda de este punto para identificar que las personas que se conecten a este servicio esten dentro del radio . . .

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, copio el codigo antes mencionado para capturar ubicación, gracias.

```js
function initAutocomplete() {
  var myLatlng = {lat: -9.0852804, lng: -78.578331};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: myLatlng,
          zoom: 18,
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:myLatlng,
            map: map
        });
        markers.push(marker);
  
   map.addListener('click', function(ele) {

            for (p in markers) {
                markers[p].setMap(null);
            }
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: ele.latLng,
                map: map
            });

            markers.push(marker);
            document.getElementById("txtlatitud").value = ele.latLng.lat();
            document.getElementById("txtlongitud").value = ele.latLng.lng();

            window.setTimeout(function() {
                map.panTo(marker.getPosition());
            }, 100);
        });
  
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          // Clear out the old markers.
          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers = [];

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
              console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
              return;
            }
            var icon = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            }));
   
   document.getElementById("txtlatitud").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
            document.getElementById("txtlongitud").value = place.geometry.location.lng();

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
          });
    

          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
  
  
      }
```

```css
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      #infowindow-content .title {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      #infowindow-content {
        display: none;
      }

      #map #infowindow-content {
        display: inline;
      }

      .pac-card {
        margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #pac-container {
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        margin-right: 12px;
      }

      .pac-controls {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 11px;
      }

      .pac-controls label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      #title {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 6px 12px;
      }
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
```

```html
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
 <label class="col-form-label col-sm-1 col-form-label-sm">X:</label><input type="text" name="txtlatitud" id="txtlatitud"  class="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-5" readonly>
    <label class="col-form-label col-sm-1 col-form-label-sm">Y:</label><input type="text" name="txtlongitud" id="txtlongitud" class="form-control form-control-sm col-sm-5" readonly>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDa0XSBVI-CpgcW48YRhknp8AnMD02Bmcw&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>
```

Comment: Encontraste la solucion?

Comment: hola, no supe como hacer para marcar en el mapa el radio, termine haciendo un llamado por ajax a la base de datos para que ejecute una funcion y me retorne la distancia entre los 2 puntos en metros, no se si te sirva pero por aqui dejo la funcion.

Comment: FUNCTION fn_apiAsistRetornaDistancia(
 l_latitud1 FLOAT(10,6),
 l_longitud1 FLOAT(10,6), 
 l_latitud2 FLOAT(10,6),
 l_longitud2 FLOAT(10,6)
) RETURNS DECIMAL(10,2)
BEGIN
 DECLARE l_distancia DECIMAL (10,4) DEFAULT 0;
 
 SET l_distancia = (ACOS(
        SIN(RADIANS(l_latitud1)) * SIN(RADIANS(l_latitud2)) +  COS(RADIANS(l_latitud1)) * COS(RADIANS(l_latitud2)) * COS(RADIANS(l_longitud1) - RADIANS(l_longitud2))
       ) * 6378);

 SET l_distancia = l_distancia * 1000;

 
 RETURN l_distancia;
END